# Yes/No : Is the subspace $A \times \{ b \}$ of $A \times B$ is homeomorphic to $A$?

Tags: general-topology

Yes/No : Is  the  subspace $A \times \{ b \}$ of $A \times B$ is homeomorphic to $A$?

My attempt : No

Here if we remove one point from  $A \times \{ b \}$  then  $(A \times \{ b \}) \setminus\{1\}$ is connected since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected if $n >1$

But if we remove one point from $A$  then $A \setminus \{1\}$ is not connected

so $A \times \{ b \} \not\cong A$

Comment: How does $\Bbb R^n$ come into play?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen take $x-y$ plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Your argument does not work with $A=B=\Bbb R$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $A\times B= \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}= \mathbb{R}^2$, we know that $\mathbb{R^n}$ is connected if $n >1$ i,e take $ n=2$

Comment: Whether a subspace $A$ of $X$ is connected is independent of whether $X$ is connected or not, it just depends on the subspace topology of $A$ inside $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $f\colon A\to A\times B$, $a\mapsto (a,b)$. As the basic open sets in $A\times B$ are of the form $U\times V$ with $U,V$ open, respectively, the preimage of such a set is either $U$ or empty (if $b\notin V$) and at any rate open. Hence $f$ is continuous.
The inverse map is simple the projection to first component, which is continuous by definition.